# Define attach-point programmatically

Tags: javascript, dojo

I would like to define custom widget, create a Dijit/form/Button inside and add attach point to it. But for some reason the attach-point remains invisible..

```
postCreate: function() {
  require(["dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Button, dom){
    // Create a button programmatically:
    var myButton = new Button({
      label: "Click me!",
      "data-dojo-attach-point": "myButton"
    }, "progButtonNode").startup();
  });

  console.debug(this.myButton); // returns undefined
}
```

Answer (score 2):

technically you can do it. But dojo indexes all the attach-points on parse. so if you are going to add a button dynamically then you'll have to parse the dom too.

Comment: This looks reasonable. Can you explain, please? Does parser.parse() have to be called at some point?

Comment: Thats a tricky one using 'parser.parse()' will be possible if the page was never passed before else you'll get a "already registered'" error or you can only parse the node you added by adding the 'rootNode' attribute to the parser. How I did it was to make a widget that is a button. The template of the widget will define a button with the attachpoints. That way, whenever you need a button, you can create one dynamically and attach it. You can access it from 'widgetinstance.attachpoint'. hope this helps